# Countdown clock in JS using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a countdown timer and progress bar. I have this javascript code but I can not add css, html and progress bar code to my javascript code.

```js
<script>
var hoursleft =  3;
var minutesleft = 0; 
var secondsleft =  0; 
var finishedtext = "Countdown finished!";
var end1;
if(localStorage.getItem("end1")) {
end1 = new Date(localStorage.getItem("end1"));
} else {
end1 = new Date();
end1.setMinutes(end1.getMinutes()+minutesleft);
end1.setSeconds(end1.getSeconds()+secondsleft);}
var counter = function () {
var now = new Date();
var diff = end1 - now;
diff = new Date(diff);
 var milliseconds = parseInt((diff%1000)/100)
    var sec = parseInt((diff/1000)%60)
    var mins = parseInt((diff/(1000*60))%60)
    var hours = parseInt((diff/(1000*60*60))%24);
if (hours < 10) { 
    hours = "0" + hours;} 
if (mins < 10) {
    mins = "0" + mins;}
if (sec < 10) { 
    sec = "0" + sec;}     
if(now >= end1) {     
    clearTimeout(interval);
    localStorage.setItem("end", null);
     localStorage.removeItem("end1");
     localStorage.clear();
    document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = finishedtext;
     if(confirm("TIME UP!"))
     window.location.href= "result.php";
} else {
    var value = hours+":" +mins + ":" + sec;
    localStorage.setItem("end1", end1);
    document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = value;}}
var interval = setInterval(counter, 1000);
</script>
```

can someone please help me to add css and progressbar with this countdown timer as shows the picture??

Comment: What do you mean by cannot add `can not add css, html and progress bar` when you are already doing `document.getElementById('divCounter')`

Comment: I have timer  without css and can you help me to add a progressbar with this countdown timer?

Comment: just add `<div id ="divCounter"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand your question completely. But here are some ideas I would come up with.

- maybe the html part of your code got lost by copying it into your Post.
- I assume you understood the [Basics about adding a script to html code.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp)
- I made a super simple example based on your code:

  ```
  <html>
    <body>
      <progress id="progressBar" value="22" max="100"></progress>
      <div id="divCounter"></div>
    </body>
  </html>

  <script>
  var hoursleft =  0;
  var minutesleft = 5;
  var secondsleft =  0;
  var finishedtext = "Countdown finished!";
  var end1;
  var progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar')
  if(localStorage.getItem("end1")) {
    end1 = new Date(localStorage.getItem("end1"));
  } else {
    end1 = new Date();
    end1.setHours(end1.getHours()+hoursleft); // Why is this line missing?
    end1.setMinutes(end1.getMinutes()+minutesleft);
    end1.setSeconds(end1.getSeconds()+secondsleft);
  }
  progressBar.max = end1 - new Date();


  var counter = function () {
    var now = new Date();
    var diff = end1 - now;
    diff = new Date(diff);
    var milliseconds = parseInt((diff%1000)/100)
    var sec = parseInt((diff/1000)%60)
    var mins = parseInt((diff/(1000*60))%60)
    var hours = parseInt((diff/(1000*60*60))%24);

    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
      }
    if (mins < 10) {
        mins = "0" + mins;
      }
    if (sec < 10) {
        sec = "0" + sec;}
    if(now >= end1) {
      clearTimeout(interval);
      localStorage.setItem("end", null);
      localStorage.removeItem("end1");
      localStorage.clear();
      document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = finishedtext;
      if(confirm("TIME UP!")) window.location.href= "result.php";
    } else {
        progressBar.value = progressBar.max - (end1-now);
        var value = hours+":" +mins + ":" + sec;
        localStorage.setItem("end1", end1);
        document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = value;
    }
  }
  var interval = setInterval(counter, 1000);
  </script>
  ```

I hope that helps. Don't hesitate to make your question more clear.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but when the time has expired,"result.php" appears empty(sending the query from current page to the result.php page does not work)!! any idea please ?